# How to change bdb cache size in mysql?

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin

I would like to change variable bdb cache size (bdb_cache_size) on my mysql database to be able to import bigger SQL files (yes, i've set all other variables for example in php.ini to higher values and it does not work) in phpmyadmin.

How can I do that?

Comment: not sure what the bdb_cache_size has to do with importing SQL files in PHP MyAdmin - are you using berkeley DB tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're really using BDB in your MySQL database, check you don't have skip-bdb in your my.cnf. Most installations disable it (and disable it this way) by default.

Berkeley DB is going away very soon in MySQL, so if you're using it, I'd recommend you shift to InnoDB (or at the very least MyISAM).

Comment: BDB support will be removed.As of MySQL 5.1, BDB is not supported.